# Gdal raster to polygon in QGIS3 (Python3)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

What shall I install to be able to run the GDAL algoritms in python3 in qgis3?

In Windows if I install gdal-python version 2.4.0-3 I get the gdal_polygonize.bat file, but it required python2.7 to be installed, is this a bug or I'm I missing something?

Comment: The OSgeo4w qgis installer should come with all you need to run GDAL, you may be missing some path references in your environment variables while running python. Can you provide the code you're trying to execute along with any errors it might have raised?

Comment: I'm trying to use the tool `polygonize (raster to vector)`, which tries to call on `gdal_polygonize.bat`. That file is in my bin folder after I install `gdal-python version 2.4.0-3`.